# Link three drop down boxes horizontally with a line in html

Tags: html, css

How to link three drop down boxes horizontally with a line in html? Suppose A B C are the three drop down boxes, I want to link them horizontally like this A----B----C. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to accomplish this with flexbox and a horizontal line created via a psuedo-element. See CSS comments for explanation!

```css
.boxes {
  /* create a flexbox and align elements */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* allow child elements to position off this parent */
  position: relative;
}

.boxes::before {
  /* create psuedo-element */
  content: '';
  background: black;
  /* position element to center vertically and fill horizontally */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  height: 4px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  /* position behind content */
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <select>
    <option>A</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>B</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>C</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: The horizontal line between the drop down is missing. The output is like   A    B    C

Comment: @ManojStack I don't understand. Did you click "Run code snippet" to see the demo?